# Unlogical Logic in PHP

Tags: php, operator-keyword

Consider a function that returns an Integer or false:

I can check for false with:

```
if(false == my_function()) {
    echo "do something";
}
```

However if I want to negate the logic:

```
if(true == my_function()) {
    echo "do something";
}
```

The second example evaluates true in all cases - even when false is returned. How is that even remotely possible. How can I check for a not-false return.

Comment: `var_dump(my_function());` returns what?

Comment: Why not just use `===` instead ?

Comment: @smith in my tests I am returning 2,3, false, false, false. But even false evaluates to true

Comment: It doesn't. Not for me at least. If I set my function to return false, it does exactly what it should do. I suspect there's more to your function than we can assume. You should update with actual code

Comment: https://ideone.com/w9A05A works for me

Comment: @Arvind true === has the opposite effect, my expression never evluates as true, even when 2 or 3 is returned

Comment: `if (!empty(my_function()))` btw, you should avoid returning different types if the function is used in a condition, you could do the checking in the function and just return true false

Comment: if (my_function() != false)   or  (!my_function() != true)

Comment: Why use a strict boolean value and use loose comparison? Makes no sense. If you're going to use loose check then just do `if (my_function())` to return any truey like value. If your function returns bool true/false then check for these - be explicit and keep things right :)

Comment: == true means truthy/truth-like, not === boolean true, if you understand that, then logical logic

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of my_function please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

true isn't false.

```
<?php
function return_false()
{
    return false;
}

var_dump(true == return_false());
```

Output:

```
bool(false)
```

Further:

```
function return_one()
{
    return 1;
}

function return_zero()
{
    return 0;
}

var_dump(true == return_one());
var_dump(true == return_zero());
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

A positive integer is truthy.
0 is falsy.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible that `true` would be equal to something "falsy" (see [PHP boolean documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)). Anyways you should always use **(not) identical** (!==/===) rather than **(not) equal** (!=/==) operator and compare only same data types in php to avoid some weird implicit type conversions.

For example

```
// DO
if ($number > 0) {...}
if ($number !== 0) {...}
// DON'T
if ($number) {...}
if ($number == true) {...}
if ($number != 0) {...}

// DO
if (count($array) > 0) {...}
if (!empty($array)) {...}
// DON'T
if ($array) {...}
if (count($array)) {...}

// DO
if (strlen($string) > 0) {...}
if (!empty($string)) {...}
// DON'T
if ($string) {...}

// and so on ...
```

Comment: Does your function returns "false" ? I mean false between quotes, like it's a string so it's a non-empty value so it's true...

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of my_function please ?

Comment: Both of you maybe wanted to comment on the question I guess

Comment: you're right, sorry about that